# Panagram python code

Tags: python

Write a function named isPanagram() that accepts a string parameter and determines if all of the 
letters of the alphabet are used at least once. NOTE: Capitalization should not matter. For example: 
isPanagram(“The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog”) should return True.

I made a code but it doesn't seem to work , i listed all the alphabets and said that if the phrase matches the alphabets to give true/ false. it only works if I put the alphabets in a straight line, is there a function that says that if it contains these alphabets to give true/ false no matter the order or even if it is a sentence

Comment: Start by looking at more examples of input and output. Then try to write, in English, the steps it takes to solve the problem.

Comment: There's an obvious brute-force way which involves 26*2 lines looking something like `if 'a' not in the_string: can_be_panagram=False`.  But that'd be silly.  At least it's a place to start, though, because then you can think of what tools you know about which can be used to abstract away repetition: loops and lists and strings (which can also be iterated over).  And then you can think of even higher-level descriptions of the problem (such as sets).  But start with something simple first.  (PS: the `string` module will come in handy, both for functions and constants.)

Comment: looks like you don't need to know where to start, because complete solutions to your homework will be delivered from some rep-hungry answerers soon

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
def isPanagram(sentence):
    alphabet = string.lowercase[:26]   # list of letters a-z
    return all(letter in sentence.lower() for letter in alphabet)
```

1. The function `all` will return true if all elements in a list are true
2. The list comprehension inside goes over all the letters of `alphabet` and checks if they are in your `sentence` after it has been changed to all lowercase with `.lower()`.

Comment: This many seem too silly but Im pretty new at Python , I dont understand why there is [import string] and why is there (sentence) inside the parenthesis in this statement
def isPanagram(sentence):

Comment: I may have overestimated your familiarity with Python. If you are at square 1, you should really pick up a good introductory Python text. The `import string` is loading the `string` library. I did that so I could use the `string.lowercase` function to get a list of letters because I'm lazy :). The `(sentance)` means that the function takes 1 input parameter called `sentence`. Then you can call the function like `isPangram("test")` or `isPangram("how about this one")`

Comment: yeah I am pretty new at this , is there a way to do it without importing the string library ?

Comment: Well, you could type out the value of `string.lowercase[:26]` yourself. As indicated, it's just a "list of letters a-z", which is not that hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of all the letters in the alphabet. Once that is done, use a for loop which uses a try/except method to check if `i in (yourlist) == True`. If at any point it passes a ValueError exception then you can be sure your string is not a pangram.

Comment: Note that using exceptions for non exceptional circumstances is often regarded as poor programming practice... although there is a python idiom of "it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission"

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import string


def isPanagram(a):
    text = a.lower()
    for le in string.ascii_lowercase:
        if text.find(le) == -1:
            return False
    return True


print isPanagram("ABCDEFGHijklmnopQRSTuvwxyz")
print isPanagram("ABCDEFGHijklmnop")
```

Comment: I made a code but it doesn't seem to work , i listed all the alphabets and said that if the phrase matches the alphabets to give true/ false. it only works if I put the alphabets in a straight line, is there a function that says that if it contains these alphabets to give true/ false no matter the order or even if it is a sentence

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample code:

```
def isPanagram(arg_str):
    alphabetList = [ chr(alphababet) for alphababet in xrange(65,91)] # create a list of all english letter in uppercase
    upperString = arg_str.upper()       #cast all alphabet to uppercase in the give string
    result = True                       #unless a alphabet is missing we will return true, so initializing to true
    for alph in alphabetList:           #for each alphabet character
        result = result * (alph in upperString) #multiply result with whether this alphabet exists or not (becomes zero if any not found)
        continue
    return result
```